# What is the complexity of a prime algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, conditional-statements, complexity-theory

I would like to know what is the complexity of this algorithm. N>=3 an integer as an imput. Thank you !

```
initialisation : i=2
LOOP:
if N%i==0
     return 1; 
if i == [sqrt(N)]
     return 0; 
i= i + 1;
```

Comment: The only time `N == sqrt(N)` is when `N == 1`. As written, that code has complexity O(1). Did you perhaps intend it to be in a loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "N is a binary number"?

Comment: All number variables (integers, floats etc.) in computers are stored as binary numbers.

Comment: @Lamaman just FYI, I suspect the reason your question is getting down-voted is because it looks like "please do my homework for me".  I wouldn't worry too much about it, but in the future, you should read the [documentation on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and generally show more effort to solve problems yourself in order to avoid down-voting.

Comment: If my answer answers the question for you, please indicate that it is correct by clicking the green checkmark.  Otherwise, it would be great if you could clarify what it is that remains to be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
initialisation : i=2
LOOP:
if N%i==0
     return 1;       # 1 <-----
if i == [sqrt(N)]
     return 0;       # 2 <-----
i= i + 1;
```

Case 1: N is even.  Then we are done in `O(1)` - see line (`# 1`).  Or N is odd, and non-prime.  Then we are done when we hit some divisor of N (this would happen before the square root, or at the same time).

Case 2: N is prime.  Then we will hit `[ n^0.5 ]` numbers (see line `# 2`) before completing.

However, as @Lutzl indicates in their comment, a precise calculation might consider the [runtime of the division involved](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/251105/122343).  This is a bit ill-posed since we don't know what multiplication and division algorithms are used.  But total runtime would be `O(max{a * sqrt(N), sqrt(N)})` where `O(a)` is the runtime of the `N % i == 0` check.  I assume here that the actual square root calculation is effectively constant time and is only done once, so `O(n^0.5)` is because that's how many iterations you get before the algorithm ends for a prime input.

Comment: Why did you single out the case where `n` is even? That's not really different from `n` being divisible by 3 or 5.

Comment: Hm, good point.  Because `i` was initialized to `2`, but now I saw that my answer is incorrect for that reason.

Comment: I would not say it is wrong. The result `O(N^0.5)` you got is correct.

Comment: @Henry it's correct iff OP means to denote rounding with `[ * ]`.  But if that does not connote rounding then we skip the square root entirely, in which case it's `O(n)`.

Comment: As division and square root have a cost that also depends on `N`, the complexity would more precisely be `O(N^0.5*M(log(N)))` where `M(x)=x^2` is the cost for digit-by-digit multiplication down to `M(x)=O(x\log(x)log(log(x)))` or similar for FFT based multiplication, Schönhage-Strassen.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually yes, I wanted to say by [sqrt(N)] the rounding of [sqrt(N)] ,sorry.
@Lutzl I am little lost with what you wrote.. Why is there the log function and what is the cost digit-by-digit ?

Comment: @Lamaman if this answers your question, please indicate so by checking the green check-mark.  Otherwise, it would be helpful if you could clarify your question with whatever it is that you are still confused about.  Thanks.

Comment: In computing asymptotic complexities, you are investigating behavior for arbitrarily large inputs. That requires some kind of BigInteger type with a variable number of digits. Then the arithmetic operations do no longer have a unit cost. -- Note that the complexity class is exponential, as that relates the input size `x=log(n)` to the run-time `O(2^(0.5x*)*M(x))`.